# “from now” vs “from now on”

Tags: idioms, american-english, mathematics

In scientific writing, I sometimes introduce variables in the introduction section as follows:

> The number of gizmos is expoinential in the number of hickeys (for which we write ℎ from now on). […] We ask ourselves how the following quantities grow with ℎ: the number of doodahs, thingums, and whatsits.

I'm often extremely tight on space, so, I wonder whether I could shorten this to

> The number of gizmos is expoinential in the number of hickeys (for which we write ℎ from now).  […] We ask ourselves how the following quantities grow with ℎ: the number of doodahs, thingums, and whatsits.

Is this shortening (“from now on” → “from now”) possible without a change in the meaning? Would the short version sound normal or unusual?

I welcome answers from mathematicians who are native AmE speakers and have an excellent command of English.

Comment: 'hereafter _h_'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! Or “hereinafter ℎ”?

Comment: @GeekestGeek hereinafter works fine but is most commonly used in legal speech. Hereafter and also henceforth are more general, relating not just to the document.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say

> (which we represent by *h*),

which is slightly shorter and more formal than either of your suggestions.

There's no need for "from now on" at all.

Comment: *Which we represent by ℎ* sounds great, but it might be misinterpreted as a parenthetical side remark rather than an introduction of a variable.